# Update ng-model value of checkbox value on the basis of other checkbox ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to update a checkbox on the basis of other checkbox.

Here is my first checkbox that is enabled and user can change its value;

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkAddVerification" name="chkAddVerification" 
  ng-model="chkAddVerification" ng-checked="chkAddVerification">
  Add Verification
</label>
```

And this is second checkbox that is disabled and updated according to first checkbox value;

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkSendCodeByEmail" name="chkSendCodeByEmail" 
   ng-model="chkSendCodeByEmail" ng-disabled="true" ng-checked="chkAddVerification">
   By Email
</label>
```

This is how I'm trying to bind first checkbox ng-model value to second checkbox ng-checked : `ng-checked="chkAddVerification"`

Apparently it is working fine (checking/ unchecking of second according to first one) but it does not update `ng-model` value of second checkbox.

If I check first checkbox `chkAddVerification`, second one also checks accordingly but ng-model  `chkSendCodeByEmail` has false value in it.

What I'm missing here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-model` and `ng-checked` are meant not to be used together.
You can use ng-change for the same

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkAddVerification" name="chkAddVerification" 
  ng-model="chkAddVerification" ng-change="chkSendCodeByEmail = chkAddVerification">
  Add Verification
</label>

<label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkSendCodeByEmail" name="chkSendCodeByEmail" 
   ng-model="chkSendCodeByEmail" ng-disabled="true">
   By Email
</label>
```

working example http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/36066/

Comment: "ng-model and ng-checked are meant to be used together" are meant or not meant?

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('demo', []);
angular.module('demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function () {
 
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl" class="modal-demo">
   <label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkAddVerification" name="chkAddVerification" 
  ng-model="chkAddVerification" ng-click="chkSendCodeByEmail=chkAddVerification">
  Add Verification,{{chkAddVerification}}
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkSendCodeByEmail" name="chkSendCodeByEmail" 
   ng-model="chkSendCodeByEmail" ng-disabled="true">
   By Email,{{chkSendCodeByEmail}}
</label>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On applying, **ng-click="chkSendCodeByEmail=chkAddVerification"** the other modal value will be updated.

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkAddVerification" name="chkAddVerification" 
  ng-model="chkAddVerification" ng-click="chkSendCodeByEmail=chkAddVerification">
  Add Verification
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkSendCodeByEmail" name="chkSendCodeByEmail" 
   ng-model="chkSendCodeByEmail" ng-disabled="true">
   By Email
</label>
```

Comment: this will also change the model of second checkbox on clicking the first one

Comment: but it does not check 2nd checkbox

Comment: i have created a snippet above u can run it